# Android Fragment error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm doing an app in Android and I'm trying to set some fragments but every time I launch the app it crash with two errors:

`MainActivity: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment`

`MainActivity@ca3678d must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Searching for the internet I found a lot of people that fixed them changing the XML file from android::name too class. I did it and still happens to me.

I use this code to navigate into the fragment:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.search_fragment, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

My Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And I implement it in the activity_main:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/search_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.onelio.app.SearchFragment"/>
```

How can I fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix static and dynamic `Fragment` usage.  When you include a `<fragment>` element in your layout you are telling the system to inflate the class `com.onelio.app.SearchFragment` and insert it into the layout.  *It cannot be changed dyanmically*.

When you create a new fragment (via a call to new `SearchFragment()`, or better yet a static method `SearchFragment.createInstance()`) you are creating a *dynamic* fragment which can be added via a `FragmentTransaction` to a *view* within the owning `Activity` (or other `Fragment`) layout.

See [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more details and example code on `Fragment` usage.